# Avoid pass by reference in Guzzle 6 Asynchronous by Pool

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

Using Guzzle 6, I have tested the Pool/Promise Asynchronous with the following code:

```
    $client = new  \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $urls = [];
    for($i = 1; $i<10; $i++) {
       $urls[] = ''https://httpbin.org/get?id='.$i;
    }    

    $requests = function ($urls){
        if(!empty($urls)) {
            foreach($urls as $uri){
                yield new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $uri);
            }
        }
    };
    $values = [];
    $pool = new \GuzzleHttp\Pool($client, $requests($urls), [
        'concurrency' => 5,
        'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) use (&$values){
            // this is delivered each successful response
            return $values[]=$response->getStatusCode();
        },
        'rejected' => function ($reason, $index){
            // this is delivered each failed request
            //dd($reason);
            return $reason->getResponse();
        },
    ]);

// Initiate the transfers and create a promise
    $promise = $pool->promise();

// Force the pool of requests to complete.
    $promise->wait();
    var_dump($values);
```

Is there a way or a refactor that will enable me to not pass by reference the $values and rather receive the results from `$promise->wait();` instead?

As seen in: http://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#async-requests

There is a way to do Promise\Settle if we want to ignore all the rejected promises and the wait will return the value returned within the result array.

Comment: Why should you pass `$values` by reference at the very first place?

Comment: @revo in order to the get the response back since the function returns the promises into $pool.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly. You need to pass `$values` to store fulfilled requests but there is no need to pass it by reference. However to have all responses in one place you can use static `batch()` method of `Pool` class:

```
$responses = Pool::batch($client, $requests(10), [
    'concurrency' => 5,
    'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) {
    },
    'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
    },
]);
```

Then you have an object of `Response` class by iterating over `$responses`:

```
foreach ($responses as $response) {
    var_dump($response->getBody()->getContents());
}
```